# GetFileAsync does not return file after saving it

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, storagefile

I have the following method, which saves a file to my LocalFolder on the Windows Phone

```
public async Task<bool> SaveValueByKey(string filename, KeyValuePair<string, string> dataToSave)
{
    var appData = ApplicationData.Current;

    // Good Save documentation - http://chriskoenig.net/2012/09/07/windows-8-games-and-roaming-data/
    StorageFile file = await appData.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    try
    {
        // Delete the key if it already exists, then replace.
        IEnumerable<string> content = await this.LoadFileContents(filename);
        if (content.Any(l => l.StartsWith(string.Format("{0}==", dataToSave.Key))))
        {
            await this.DeleteKey(filename, dataToSave.Key);
        }

        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, string.Format("{0}=={1}", dataToSave.Key, dataToSave.Value));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I then later try to load the data back using this method.

```
public async Task<string> LoadValueFromKey(string filename, string key)
{
    var appData = ApplicationData.Current;
    StorageFile file = null;

    try
    {
        file = await appData.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    IEnumerable<string> contents = await this.LoadFileContents(filename);
    string element = string.Format("{0}==", key);
    if (!contents.Any(line => line.StartsWith(element)))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    return contents.First(line => line.StartsWith(element))
        .ToString()
        .Substring(element.Length);
}
```

The call to `GetFileAsync` returns null, even though a valid file object was returned to me after the `CreateFileAsync` call.

Am I missing something here? Are there declarations I need to make? I didn't see any that were related to this.

**Edit**

The filename and key values are passed in from a Repository, which declares them like this:

```
private const string tokenFilename = "UserSession.dat";

private const string tokenKey = "UserToken";
```

**Edit 2**

The exception being thrown is a FileNotFound exception with the following message.

```
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Lifestream.App.Mobile.WindowsApp.Services.FileStorageService.<LoadValueFromKey>d__16.MoveNext()
```

**Edit 3**

If I run the app as a Windows app (this is a Universal app), the file is saved and loaded without any issues. If I target the Windows Phone then the File Not Found exception is thrown when I try to save and then load. This seems to be specific to the phone and I can't figure why

Comment: Those `catch (Exception)` clauses smell really bad. Try checking those to see if it's throwing or something, and in any case fix them to be far less general and data-loss-y.

Comment: The exception being thrown is a FileNotFound exception

Comment: The issue I have is that Microsoft doesn't tell me what exceptions those methods might throw, so I'm just left guessing. I use Exception for now and as Exceptions creep up during unit testing, I add catches for more specific exceptions

Comment: IOException would be pretty common for that for, well, I/O stuff. But it's usually better to have your program crash and die in testing because it failed to handle an unexpected exception *at all* than to swallow an exception and have to remember to log it and put in the right `catch` clause.

Comment: I don't disagree, but my question is why loading the file throws the FileNotFound exception and not so much how I am catching the exceptions. Appreciate the input on it though

Comment: I should note that the Application.Current.LocalFolder.RelativeFolder value changes each time I start the app, but the actual Path of the folder remains the same. I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: What line is the exception being thrown from? That `this.LoadFileContents` call looks a little fishy. Other than that I don't really know.

Comment: The line containing `file = await appData.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);` throws the exception. The file names are the same since I am passing in the same const value when invoking both methods.

Comment: Just in case: How do you call your both methods? Are you awaiting them on the same therad? Is there a chance for a race condition?

Comment: No there's no race condition. The save call happens when I click a save button. Once it is done I restart the app which attempts to load it

Comment: If I run the app as a Windows App, the file is saved and loaded without any issue. If I save and then load on Windows Phone then the File Not Found exception is thrown. It's specific to the phone for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this. The issue was with the Windows Phone project properties. Properties->Debug had the "Uninstall then reinstall my package" option checked, which was deleting all of the saved files I was creating each time I re-ran the application.